# Creating Instance for run time type throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

My code is throwing an Exception and I don't know why. Maybe somebody is able to help me out.

Exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor on type
>   'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' not found.'

My code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        typeof(Test1).GetProperty("Name").SetValue(t, "tetst");

        // throws error:
        var c = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test).GetProperty("Test1test").GetType());

        typeof(Test).GetProperty("Test1test").SetValue(c, t);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Test1test = new Test1();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Test1 Test1test { get; set; }
}

public class Test1
{
    public Test1()
    { }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test1))`?

Answer (score 0):

You need change from

```
var c = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test).GetProperty("Test1test").GetType());
```

change to

```
var c = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test));
```

`typeof(Test).GetProperty("Test1test").GetType()` will return Test1 type

but you want to set property `Test1test` so you need create instance of `Test`

`typeof(Test).GetProperty("Test1test").GetType()` return `RuntimePropertyInfo` type, not `Test1` type.

Comment: I tested the code, it worked, he want to set Test1test so he need create instance of Test